# Sum Data in Overlapping Time Intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to create summary statistics for a set of filters that operate in a lead/lag fashion.

*A short description on lead/lag:*

*When a new filter is put online, it is put in the lag position meaning water passes through it after it passes through the primary (aka lead) filter. When the lead filter is clogged, the current lag filter is moved into the lead position. To summarize, a filter starts in the lag position then is bumped into the lead position.*

*Visually, you can imagine it like this:*

[image: Filter Diagram]

What I need to do is sum the entire time a single filter was online, in both the lead or lag position.

Here's sample data:

```
structure(list(record_timestamp = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192060,1608192120, 1608192180, 1608192240, 1608192300, 1608192360, 1608192420,1608192480, 1608192540, 1608192600, 1608192660, 1608192720, 1608192780,1608192840, 1608192900, 1608192960, 1608193020, 1608193080, 1608193140,1608193200, 1608193260, 1608193320, 1608193380, 1608193440, 1608193500,1608193560, 1608193620, 1608193680, 1608193740, 1608193800), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), flow = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), lag_start = structure(c(1608192000,1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, 1608192660, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260,1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), lead_start = c("#N/A","#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A", "#N/A","#N/A", "#N/A", "12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11","12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11","12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:11", "12/17/2020 8:21","12/17/2020 8:21", "12/17/2020 8:21", "12/17/2020 8:21", "12/17/2020 8:21","12/17/2020 8:21", "12/17/2020 8:21", "12/17/2020 8:21", "12/17/2020 8:21","12/17/2020 8:21")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -31L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(record_timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector")), polish_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), lead_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess","collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

My thought is to "unnest" them and just accept there will be duplicate timestamps, but each row will only be associated with one filter. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? The unnested DF would look like:

```
structure(list(record_timestamp = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192060,1608192120, 1608192180, 1608192240, 1608192300, 1608192360, 1608192420,1608192480, 1608192540, 1608192600, 1608192660, 1608192720, 1608192780,1608192840, 1608192900, 1608192960, 1608193020, 1608193080, 1608193140,1608193200, 1608192660, 1608192720, 1608192780, 1608192840, 1608192900,1608192960, 1608193020, 1608193080, 1608193140, 1608193200, 1608193260,1608193320, 1608193380, 1608193440, 1608193500, 1608193560,1608193620,1608193680, 1608193740, 1608193800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), flow = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lag_start = structure(c(1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000, 1608192000,1608192000,1608192000, 1608192000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), lead_start = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660, 1608192660,1608192660, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1608193260,1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260,1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260, 1608193260), class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), filter_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -41L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(record_timestamp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector")), polish_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character","collector")), lead_start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector")), filter_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double","collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess","collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

I realize however, this will double the size of the data I'm working with, which is already several years of one minute data. So if there is a way to do this without doubling up timestamps, that would be preferred.

Finally, the end goal is to have a small summary DF that looks like:

```
   Filter ID  |  Total Flow
----------------------------
       1      |     370
       2      |     250
      ...     |     ...
```

Comment: Changed the columns to POSIXct instead of chr. There is not a column for that. What I can do is derive all the intervals for each filter. For example: data %>%
  distinct(lag_start, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(changeout_interval = interval(lag_start, lead(lead_start)))

Comment: With this you end up with the start and stop time for each filter, or NA for a filter that is currently in use. I suppose the current datetime could be used as the end point for those filters. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the details. Please see answer below. Does this give the desired result? Or please let me know if I'm missing some other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing additional information. It seems that you could `group_by` the `lag_start` time alone. Then, you could calculate the total `flow` while in that position (either lead or lag). After that, you can assign filter numbers in sequence, and then the total filter `flow` would be the sum of `flow` in both current row and following row. Does this give the desired result?

```
df %>%
  group_by(lag_start) %>%
  summarise(flow_per_position = sum(flow)) %>%
  mutate(filter_id = row_number(),
         total_filter_flow = flow_per_position + lead(flow_per_position, default = 0))
```

**Output**

```
  lag_start           flow_per_position filter_id total_filter_flow
  <dttm>                          <dbl>     <int>             <dbl>
1 2020-12-17 08:00:00               220         1               370
2 2020-12-17 08:11:00               150         2               250
3 2020-12-17 08:21:00               100         3               100
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers the ultimate question I was after. I'm now realizing however, I may need to "unnest" the filters for easier plotting, but that's a separate question.